# How to use Collection.shuffle correctly?

Tags: java, collections, shuffle

```
List<Character> word_to_show = new ArrayList<Character>();
for(char ch:jumbled_word.toCharArray()){
word_to_show.add(ch);
}
Collections.shuffle(word_to_show);
```

this is what I'm using to shuffle a word and then println() will show it in the console. But many times it's happening that, say if the word is DO, after shuffling i'm getting DO again and not OD(which I want to get). Any suggestions?

Comment: are you always using a list with only 2 entries? If so, chances of shuffling actually doing something would of course be 50/50

Comment: no i'll be using words of varying letter lengths. But how can I make sure that no word is shown exactly as it is after shuffling?

Comment: Sometimes I get OD too. But I want to ensure it. Can't a piece of code do it? Please suggest.

Comment: @ArhatBaid You'll have to check if shuffling maintained the original order afterwards then yourself. you can probably do that in a loop

Comment: @Dragondraikk i've tried checking in a loop, but as i have to shuffle() the word again, the result is not the desired one. :-(

Comment: @ArhatBaid I've added an answer that should hopefully help you

Answer (score 0):

If the word is DO you have 50% of possibilities to retrieve DO and 50% to retrieve OD.

Your code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to shuffle in a loop that has a condition which ensures that the result is different from the original String.

Assuming that `String jumbledWord` is your original String:

```
String originalWord = jumbledWord;
while(originalWord.equals(jumbledWord)){
    List<Character> wordToShow = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for(char ch:jumbledWord.toCharArray()){
        wordToShow.add(ch);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(wordToShow);
    jumbledWord = new String(wordToShow.toArray());
}
```

After this, `jumbledWord` will contain your scrambled String which is now guaranteed to be different from the original String.

Comment: this doesn't work either. I have also tried if-else. :-(